# Racket - Eval S-Expressions

Tags: racket, s-expression

A S-Expression is considered as a Number, a String, a Symbol, a Bool, an Image, empty or a List-of S-Expressions.

How do I achieve to make racket eval my S-Expression?
'(1 2 (+ 2 1))) should yield (list 1 2 3).

I want to do this with Beginning Student Language with List-Abbreviations.

I have no idea how to achieve this, how do I know when a plus sign is coming up?
Probably easy one for you guys here...

```
(define (eval s)
     (cond
        [(...) ...]
        [(...) ...]
        [else ...]))
```

Comment: use recursion, and `first`, `rest`, `null?` and `pair?`.

Comment: Could you please guide me?
Im stuck.

How do I recognize the + sign?

 '(1 2 (+ 2 1))) is nothing else than (list 1 2 (list '+ 2 1))
The problem is how do I recognize this + sign and yield it?

Comment: by using `eq?`: `(cond ... ((eq? s '+) +) ...)`. there's also `number?`, `symbol?`, ...

Comment: Does not work, it says it expects the first argument to be a symbol, but list '+ 2 1 given... :/

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ExeUbrynvNE

Comment: include the  code you used ([mcve]), the test call you made, and its results (if it was an error,  copy-paste full error message).